# Gstreamer blocked tee

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am testing Gstreamer with the pipeline below. Basically a tee'd video input with two file outputs.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! 
tee name=t ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/assets/out1.mp4
t. ! queue ! valve drop=true ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/assets/out2.mp4 -e
```

I would expect the pipeline to write to `out1.mp4` while the valve blocks output to `out2.mp4`. However, for some reason, both files remain empty. What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `async=false` for the valve-ed path filesink. Please note that valve also discards events like EOS. Perhaps you are better of dropping samples via a PadProbe. This requires a real application though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is that very surprising?

Comment: I actually started with a gst-python app and probes, but I ran into the same issue. I thought this command-line example would be the easiest to reproduce.

Comment: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true !  tee name=t ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=out1.mp4 t. ! queue ! valve drop=true ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=out2.mp4 async=false` actually works for me. Its just that the Ctrl-C at the end does hang because the EOS is not properly propagated.

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally typed `async=true` instead. Many thanks!